# About limit and series of double complex sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\{a_{n,m}\}_{n,m \in \Bbb N}$ be a double complex sequence such that:

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{n,m} |^2 =0$$

I would like to know if the following relation is true:

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,m} =0$$

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No thats not true. Take $a_{n,m}=\frac{1}{nm}$.

Comment: Now it does. I corrected the typo. Thank you!

Comment: ok thanks so much, but if i know that it is convergent, in this case is it true?

Comment: What do you mean by _i know that it is convergent_?

Comment: i mean that $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,m} $ is convergent

Comment: No, why should $\lim_m \sum_n a_{n,m} <\infty $ imply $\lim_m \sum_n a_{n,m} =0$ or what do you mean?

Comment: i mean if $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert a_{n,m} \rvert ^2 =0$ and $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,m}$ is convergent => $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,m} =0$

Comment: But this is exactly your question and I already gave you a counterexample.

Comment: excuse me, your counterexample is for $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,m} $ not convergent